# iframe Onload Visibility

Tags: iframe

I am trying to hide an iframe until it is loaded by I keep getting an error with the following code:

```
    jquery("some stuff">.html("<iframe frameborder='0' vspace='0' hspace='0' marginwidth='0'
 allowtransparency='true' scrolling='no' marginheight='0' 
style='visibility:hidden;' onload="this.style.visibility='visible';" width='600' 
class='frm'></iframe>").appendTo('body');
```

But it returns an error "syntax error this.style.visibility".

Can anyone help ?

**edit**:fixed spelling but now get the error

'missing ) after argument list'

Answer (score 3):

You have a typo. Should be

```
this.style.visibility='visible';
```

Comment: hey :) thanks. yeah i fixed that but now i get 

missing ) after argument list

Answer (score 2):

required exit quotes \ and \

onload=\"this.style.visibility='visible';\"